# pyspark write dataframe to hdfs fails

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have the below to codes to create 2 files from pyspark data frames. First one is executed successfully. The second line fails with an error. Can someone help me to identify the root cause?

```
df_Test_cases.write.format("csv").mode('overwrite').save("hdfs://hd0/data/sample.db/test_result_tc/result.csv") # no issues
df_summary.write.format("csv").mode('overwrite').save("hdfs://hd0/data/sample.db/test_result_py/result.csv") # fails
```

Here is the error log

```
> 18/10/11 09:54:19 WARN TaskMemoryManager: Failed to allocate a page
> (1048576 bytes), try again.
>     
>     18/10/11 09:54:19 ERROR Utils: Exception encountered
>     java.io.IOException: Could not allocate memory to grow BytesToBytesMap
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$joins$UnsafeHashedRelation$$read(HashedRelation.scala:267)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation$$anonfun$readExternal$1.apply$mcV$sp(HashedRelation.scala:214)
> 
>

 in  module 
    df_summary.write.format("csv").mode('overwrite').save("hdfs://hd0/data/sample.db/test_result_py/result.csv") # fails
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 595, in save
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2153.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:437)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:473)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 25.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 25.0 (TID 31, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Could not allocate memory to grow BytesToBytesMap
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$joins$UnsafeHashedRelation$$read(HashedRelation.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation$$anonfun$readExternal$1.apply$mcV$sp(HashedRelation.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation$$anonfun$readExternal$1.apply(HashedRelation.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation$$anonfun$readExternal$1.apply(HashedRelation.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation.readExternal(HashedRelation.scala:213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1840)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$1.getNext(Serializer.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.maybeCacheDiskValuesInMemory(BlockManager.scala:1185)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getLocalValues(BlockManager.scala:526)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.wholestagecodegen_init_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:392)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:389)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:844)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:844)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:186)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not allocate memory to grow BytesToBytesMap
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$joins$UnsafeHashedRelation$$read(HashedRelation.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation$$anonfun$readExternal$1.apply$mcV$sp(HashedRelation.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation$$anonfun$readExternal$1.apply(HashedRelation.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation$$anonfun$readExternal$1.apply(HashedRelation.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation.readExternal(HashedRelation.scala:213)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1840)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$1.getNext(Serializer.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.maybeCacheDiskValuesInMemory(BlockManager.scala:1185)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getLocalValues(BlockManager.scala:526)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.wholestagecodegen_init_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:392)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:389)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:844)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:844)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        ... 1 more

18/10/11 09:54:19 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Comment: Can you tell me the spark version? You can find it when you launch ./pyspark.

Comment: What happens when you do "df_summary.show(1000)" ??

Comment: @Prazy Spark version is version 1.6.3

Comment: @Shijo this means there is some problem in how you have computed df_summary. Can you post logic df_summary?

Comment: @Shijo it looks like you are saving to a hive database. Any reason you can't do `df_summary.registerAsTempTable("summary")` followed by `HiveContext.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE sample SELECT * FROM summary")`

Comment: Are u doing a join operation before saving the second dataframe ? Can you try a trivial action like df.count before saving just to verify its not an error with the code prior to "save" action.

Comment: `Lost task 0.0 in stage 25.0 (TID 31, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Could not allocate memory to grow BytesToBytesMap` this looks to me as if you should increase (driver and/or) executor memory. Try to set "--executor-memory XG" when you submit the job.

Comment: Could add schema of your DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrea said it is a memory issue. First of all I have to warn you that CSV is not the best format to write "big data", I suggest you to try others more optimized for Spark like Parquet.

However, if you really want to export the data to a CSV file then you can try two different approaches:

1. Increase the executor and driver memory: You can either modify the default Spark config in the *spark-defaults.conf* file:

> spark.executor.memory: '2G'
>
> spark.driver.memory: '4G'

2. Before running the Spark job with submit you can pass arguments modifying the previous  options [Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html):

`./bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 4g –num-executors 2 --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 2`

Another approach is to split the output file into multiple smaller selecting subsets of data and later if needed merging it locally. I would not do this, but you can try to rule out other problems apart from the memory shortage.

EDIT: Adding some links with some interesting options to tune the Spark jobs

[Cloudera How-to Tune Spark jobs](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/)

[How we Optimize Apache Spark Jobs](https://rea.tech/how-we-optimize-apache-spark-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your rows are too big, so Java throws an IOException when tries to move data (under the hood) to `BytesToBytesMap`. How many columns does your dataframe holds? Which is the column that holds the biggest data, and how big is that data?

I think you should focus on this error row:

> java.io.IOException: Could not allocate memory to grow BytesToBytesMap

[This link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-commits/201508.mbox/%3C6b19b393ccba458fb99f9c593c44416e@git.apache.org%3E) gives some hints on how this mechanism works.